# I add the order element in the css, but the positions do not change

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, responsive-design

```
<section id="home">
 <div class="container">
  <div class="row align-items-center container-items">
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <div class="info">
        <h1>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet <u style="color: rgb(165, 177, 231);">consectetur.</u> </h1>
        <p>Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Fuga, pariatur corporis! Quaerat officiis sit rerum exercitationem 
          facilis quas ex veritatis quod dolores delectus reiciendis autem dignissimos doloremque consequuntur, ad eaque possimus corrupti. 
          Fugiat, non unde labore, cupiditate nobis quis maxime error, omnis rerum tenetur officiis ea doloremque qui nihil officia?</p>
      </div>
      <ul>
        <li>
          <img src="./image/freshfood.png" alt="">
          <span><u>Fresh Foods</u> </span>
        </li>
        <li>
          <img src="./image/restaurant.png" alt="">
          <span> <u>Master Chefs</u> </span>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6 food-img">
      <div>
        <img src="image/home.png" alt="">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</section>
```

I want the home.png image and h1,p elements in the html codes to be replaced under 575.98 px. When I bring the device to these dimensions, h1,p is on the top and home.png is on the bottom. For this reason;

```
  #home .container-items  {
    display: flex;
}
#home .info{
    max-width: 100%;
    height: 15rem;
    order: 1 ;
  }
  #home .food-img{
    order: 2;
}
```

I wrote these codes. Could you please explain this to me; For the order element to work, don't I need to assign the order element in the css to the classes or ids I gave to these divs? Like the food-img and info classes in this code.

Comment: `order` only works on **direct** flex children which `.info` is not. The direct children of `. container-items` are your columns. Perhaps move the `.info` class to the column instead of a separate div.

Answer (score 0):

As Paulie_D points out, this only works on the direct children (identified by the class flex-item-1 and flex-item-2 in the code below). You can then specify the order for the child elements:

```css
#home .container-items {
  display: flex;
}
#home .info {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: 15rem;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 575.98px) {
  .container-items {
    flex-direction: column;
  }

  .flex-item-1 {
    order: 2;
  }

  .flex-item-2 {
    order: 1;
  }
}
```

```html
    <section id="home">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="row align-items-center container-items">
          <div class="col-md-6 flex-item-1">
            <div class="info">
              <h1>
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
                <u style="color: rgb(165, 177, 231)">consectetur.</u>
              </h1>
              <p>
                Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Fuga,
                pariatur corporis! Quaerat officiis sit rerum exercitationem
                facilis quas ex veritatis quod dolores delectus reiciendis autem
                dignissimos doloremque consequuntur, ad eaque possimus corrupti.
                Fugiat, non unde labore, cupiditate nobis quis maxime error,
                omnis rerum tenetur officiis ea doloremque qui nihil officia?
              </p>
            </div>
            <ul>
              <li>
                <img src="https://picsum.photos/60" alt="" />
                <span><u>Fresh Foods</u> </span>
              </li>
              <li>
                <img src="https://picsum.photos/60" alt="" />
                <span> <u>Master Chefs</u> </span>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-6 food-img flex-item-2">
            <div>
              <img src="https://picsum.photos/300/200" alt="" />
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>
```

In this case, you could just use `flex-direction: column-reverse;` though:

```css
#home .container-items {
  display: flex;
}
#home .info {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: 15rem;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 575.98px) {
  .container-items {
    flex-direction: column-reverse;
  }
}
```

```html
    <section id="home">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="row align-items-center container-items">
          <div class="col-md-6 flex-item-1">
            <div class="info">
              <h1>
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
                <u style="color: rgb(165, 177, 231)">consectetur.</u>
              </h1>
              <p>
                Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Fuga,
                pariatur corporis! Quaerat officiis sit rerum exercitationem
                facilis quas ex veritatis quod dolores delectus reiciendis autem
                dignissimos doloremque consequuntur, ad eaque possimus corrupti.
                Fugiat, non unde labore, cupiditate nobis quis maxime error,
                omnis rerum tenetur officiis ea doloremque qui nihil officia?
              </p>
            </div>
            <ul>
              <li>
                <img src="https://picsum.photos/60" alt="" />
                <span><u>Fresh Foods</u> </span>
              </li>
              <li>
                <img src="https://picsum.photos/60" alt="" />
                <span> <u>Master Chefs</u> </span>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-6 food-img flex-item-2">
            <div>
              <img src="https://picsum.photos/300/200" alt="" />
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>
```